# What is best mysql query to find comma separated subgroup in comma separated values column

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to query database to get records for having IN,US,CH in comma separated valued columns.

Query string : IN,US,EN

```
column values : IN,UST,EN,PC,US : Should match
column values : XR,TX,LN        : Should not match  
column values : XH,IN,ST        : Should match
```

I used multile where conditions with find in sets for each value breaking query string (IN,US,EN)

But i want some regex mysql optimized query.

Comment: I think you should provide your sql query or sample code to know better what you want to achieve

Comment: Consider use of [`Find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood your post, but maybe it helps for you by followed hints.

I've checked it in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dd0c/4/0)

```
CREATE TABLE SO_TEST
    (`id` int,`country_code` char(100));

INSERT INTO SO_TEST
    (`id`, `country_code`)
VALUES
    (1, 'IN,UST,EN,PC,US'),
    (2, 'XR,TX,LN'),
    (3, 'XH,IN,ST');
```

Here is query sql.

```
SELECT * FROM SO_TEST
WHERE concat(concat(',',country_code),',') REGEXP (concat(concat(',',REPLACE('IN,US,EN', ',', ',|,')),','))
```

Output result:

```
| id | country_code    | 
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | IN,UST,EN,PC,US |
| 3  | XH,IN,ST        |
```

Query sql for bug([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dd0c/3/0)):

```
SELECT * FROM SO_TEST
WHERE concat(concat(',',country_code),',') REGEXP (concat(concat(',',REPLACE('ST', ',', ',|,')),','))
```

Output result:

```
| id | country_code    | 
+----+-----------------+
| 3  | XH,IN,ST        |
```

Comment: Bug:  `US` and `ST` will match `UST`.

Comment: Thanks to @RickJames for catching bug. I've update my post.